# How can I add a gray text inside an entry in Pyhon 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I don't know If I was able to explain what I want to do.

I want to add a text inside a entry that shows what is this entry for.

For example a gray "Password" text inside a password entry. That must disappear when user starts writing a password.

I am using Python 3.8.8 and tkinter.

Comment: So what's the UI / frontend you're using ? Without that info, no one will be able to help you.

Comment: Ah I forgot. Tkinter.

Answer (score 1):

If you're beginning with Python and GUI interfaces, you should definitly have a look at `PySimpleGUI` which a is VERY easy to use wrapper for tkinter and Qt.
Also works for web applications with PySimpleGUIWeb.

Install the package with `python -m pip install pysimplegui` then try the following example:

```
import PySimpleGUI.PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [[sg.Text('My one-shot window.')],
                 [sg.InputText(key='-IN-', password_char='*')],
                 [sg.Submit(), sg.Cancel()]]

window = sg.Window('Window Title', layout)

event, values = window.read()
window.close()

text_input = values['-IN-']
sg.popup('You entered', text_input)
```

Checkout the result:
[image: Result]

Comment: Just as questions seeking tool recommendations are off topic for Stack Overflow, "try using this different tool rather than the one you want help with" is generally not a good answer - at least not without a clear argument as to why the chosen tool is not fit for purpose.

Comment: Look at 1st edition of the question which didn't even state Tkinter, so my answer wasn't off topic in the first place. Also, the tool I suggest still is a wrapper for Tkinter ;)